# Marquee:not working in Mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, marquee

My marquee is not working in Mobile devices while it is working in desktop.
It would be great if u help me out...
Thanks

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 100px){
  p{
    display: none;
  }
}
.welcome{
    font-size: 400%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <h1 class="welcome" style="color: #B9FE00;"><marquee behavior="scroll"    direction="left" >
      Our Service</marquee></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you checked it in chrome browser?

Comment: Yes @NitishKumarDiwakar

Comment: if something is **obsolete**, that doesn't necessary mean **must not be used**. So, using in comination with `css` and `js` can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.welcome{
    font-size: 400%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <marquee behavior="scroll"    direction="left" >
    <h1 class="welcome" style="color: #B9FE00;">Our Service</h1>       </marquee>
</div>
```